# Scaling and positioning of parallax layers

Tags: flutter, flame

I'm implementing a parallax background for my 2d side-scrolling game with Flame, similar to the [example](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/main/examples/lib/stories/parallax/sandbox_layer_parallax_example.dart).

The `ParallaxComponent` api seems to support only placing layers using `Alignment` which puts them to the top/center/bottom of the screen.

I wonder if there's a way to position layers more precisely and change their size. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API of `ParallaxComponent` doesn't support this yet, but what you could do is using multiple `ParallaxComponent`s on top of each other since they are `PositionComponent`s that you can place and size as you like.